# Display last postings of 5 categories on homepage

Tags: categories, homepage, excerpt

i have a question. I want to display on my homepage (template) the last postings of 5 categories as excerpts. Means excerpts from last article of cat.1, last article of cat.2 and so on, so i got then 5 articles (excerpts), each one from a differend category i.e. cat. 1-5.;

How can i make this "simply"?

EDIT: I did it so:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => '5', );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <ul class="recent-posts-2">
        <div class="cat"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(149); ?>">my 1. category</a></div>
        <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 120,120 ), array( 'class' => 'recent-thumbs' )); ?></a> 
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => '7', );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <ul class="recent-posts-2">
        <div class="cat"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(151); ?>">my 2. category</a></div>
        <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 120,120 ), array( 'class' => 'recent-thumbs' )); ?></a> 
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Dis example shows 2 excerpts of 2 cats, and i have to repeat it until i get my 5 articles. I thougt, maybe is there a better way.

Thanks, and sorry for my "great" englisch, -Orwell

Comment: What have you tried? Please **edit your question** to include your current code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you clarify what *specifically* the problem/issue is? Is it merely a question of better/more efficient coding method, or something more?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, but it seems its unnecessary code in the file, - so my question is only for more efficience and a cleaner better code if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to write the code more efficiently, though not necessarily WordPress-specific.

1. Only pass necessary args to your `get_posts()` calls

   The only critical args you need are `posts_per_page` and `category`; you can omit the rest
2. Make an array of category IDs, and loop through the array

   Loop through an array of category IDs, so you only have to use the actual loop output once

For example:

```
<?php
// Add category IDs here
$category_ids = array( 5, 7 );

// Loop through category IDs
foreach ( $category_ids as $cat_id ) {

    // Category query args
    $cat_query_args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category' => $cat_id );
    // Query posts
    $cat_query = get_posts( $cat_query_args );
    // Loop through cat query
    foreach ($cat_query as $post ) {  
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        ?> 
        <ul class="recent-posts-2">
            <div class="cat"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(149); ?>">my 1. category</a></div>
            <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 120,120 ), array( 'class' => 'recent-thumbs' )); ?></a> 
        </ul>
    }
}
?>
```

You may need to add in some other things, such as a counter for `class="recent-posts-1"`, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot. Im new in php and will try it out. Looks very good and saves lines. :)

Comment: Did it so, but now i need the page links for each cat. I have for each cat a page. The <?php echo get_page_link(); ?> dont work as i need it. Have i to make a new array to assign the page links to the categorys? Thanks :)

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add that additional question, along with relevant information to help answer it. How are pages associated with categories?